# Search a JSON column in a database

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I'm looking to see if it's possible to search multiple database rows for a specific value that's stored in a json string. For instance I have a table called `stashitems` that contains a json column `items` that stores all of a players items. I would like to search the 1500 rows of data for a specific label or name value. Below is a snippet of one players stashitems.

How could I accomplish this for the entire table? Thanks for any help!

```
{
"8": {
    "type": "item",
    "slot": 8,
    "amount": 948,
    "weight": 100,
    "name": "glass",
    "label": "Glass",
    "image": "glass.png",
    "useable": false,
    "unique": false,
    "info": ""
},
"23": {
    "type": "item",
    "slot": 23,
    "amount": 1,
    "weight": 200,
    "name": "crack_baggy",
    "label": "Bag of Crack",
    "image": "crack_baggy.png",
    "useable": true,
    "unique": false,
    "info": ""
},
"47": {
    "type": "item",
    "slot": 47,
    "amount": 1,
    "weight": 20000,
    "name": "diving_gear",
    "label": "Diving Gear",
    "image": "diving_gear.png",
    "useable": true,
    "unique": true,
    "info": []
},
"48": {
    "type": "item",
    "slot": 48,
    "amount": 1,
    "weight": 20000,
    "name": "diving_gear",
    "label": "Diving Gear",
    "image": "diving_gear.png",
    "useable": true,
    "unique": true,
    "info": []
}
}
```

MariaDB 10.4.22

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can very easily traverse JSON with the following syntax:

```
SELECT 'stashitems'
  JSON_VALUE(json_column, '$.8.type') AS type
```

see [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

It's also possible in [MySQL, though the syntax is different.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

Unfortunately, [SQLite stores only text values, so a workaround is needed.](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#:%7E:text=SQLite%20stores%20JSON%20as%20ordinary,a%20binary%20encoding%20of%20JSON.)

Comment: it is mariadb i retagged it

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities like

> ```
> SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@json, 'all', 'glass');
> ```
>
> ```
> | JSON_SEARCH(@json, 'all', 'glass') |
> | :--------------------------------- |
> | ["$.8.name", "$.8.label"]          |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @json Like '%glass%'
> ```
>
> ```
> | @json Like '%glass%' |
> | -------------------: |
> |                    1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=27d2425936c005d5afed2028dfbc9e3c)*

Comment: Not really following this, its the numbers (8, 47, etc) that throw me for a spin. This is a query I used before to pull players matching a specific bank account dollar amount
`SELECT * FROM players WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(money, '$.bank') >= 10000000;`

I want to accomplish the same thing in this instance but dont think I can with the provided snippet above

Comment: now i can't followyou you wanted to search for names and labels, so you can use the query above to find the jsons that contqains the items.

Comment: Yes so here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/XyZDgOZ.png) of my `stashitems` table. The `items` column is the JSON file and there is about 2,500 rows. How would I setup that statement to pull back all 2,500 rows that contain the JSON value "glass"?

Comment: look your json design doesn't allow to search for pattern as you have 5 different label 8,23.. and as highest point and you have for all these labels a json as values, json needs patterns like your $.bank which means label bank at the higest level with 100000001 as value, tat you can search wit pattern, your design doesn't allow that, so if you want to search fpr glasses use what i answered